# Prepopulate realm to use on different platforms

Tags: react-native, realm

I'd like to use Realm for my database in my React-Native app (android and iOS (windows too is optional)). I also want to ship my app with some prepopulated data.

I managed to write simple app that creates realm files somewhere in android. I extracted that files and put them alongside my js files in ./assets directory. I create realm by providing path to default.realm file in assets, but I'm getting error `Unable to open realm at path './assets/default.realm.management': make_dir() failed: No such file or directory`

Folder structure:

[image]

Relevant code:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        let realm = new Realm({path: './assets/default.realm'});
    }
```

1. Is there an easier way to get prepopulated *.realm file?
2. Where to put and how to import prepopulated *.realm file?

Answer (score 1):

The directories inside the application package are *read-only*. Realm requires write access to be able to work.

You need to copy the Realm file to disk before interacting with it. I haven't worked with React Native, but something like this might get you started: [React Native FS](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs)